# Speaker diarization with Node js using openai

Tags: node.js, speech-to-text, openai-api, openai-whisper, speaker-diarization

I am doing whisper transcription in the node js using openai API. I am able to get the transcriptions for chunked files using ffmpeg library. I am struggling at the point of speaker diarization with node js. It would be great if get any guidance on this.